# python pandas : Why can't I use both index_col and usecols in the same read_csv statement ? raised valueError

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

if I read in the csv file using this code :

```
    df = pd.read_csv('amazon2.csv'
                 , names=["year","state","month","number","date"]
                 , index_col = ['month']
                 , usecols=["year","state","number"]
                 , encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

would raise valueError:

```
raise ValueError("Index {col} invalid".format(col=col))

ValueError: Index month invalid
```

But would not raise error if either usecols or index_col is commented out
Thanks in advance!
the database looks like this :
[image: amazon2.csv]

Comment: It might be that you need to allow duplicates in your index. By default, an index would only have unique values I believe.

Comment: I agree with @mgrollins that the index is the most likely source of the problem. Parse it without designating that column as the index, and then sort things out in Pandas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error source is caused by that the index column name "month" is not included in the columns list :usecols.

```
df1=pd.read_csv("test.csv",index_col="month",usecols=["year","state","number","date","month"])
```

Output:

```
          year  state  number      date
month                       
Janeiro   1998   Acre       0  1998/1/1
Janeiro1  1998   Acre       1  1998/1/1
Janeiro1  1999  Acre2       2  1999/1/1
Janeiro2  2000   Acre       3  2000/1/1
Janeiro2  2000  Acre1       4  2000/1/1
```

But I agree that there should be no duplicated values in the index col.

Comment: Thank you so much!